# Setup a Django in Anaconda environment

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I am trying to setup a Django in Anaconda environment.

I have created a new environment with the name Django2. After that, I was stuck, unable to move on.

What are the actions that should be taken? Please offer some suggestions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc4ve.png)

Comment: Have you tried looking for online resources? https://pythonistaplanet.com/how-to-create-a-django-project-in-anaconda-very-easily/ came up after a quick google search. Questions here are for specific programming questions, not for tutorials on how to install/set up stuff